# Unable to update mutableList object model values Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelivedata

all wanted to update the values in the mutable list, but loop jumping out here is my code snippet.

```
for ((i, dataObject) in data.withIndex()) {
            channelsObject.getChannel(
                dataObject.remoteChannelId,
                ChatCallbackListener<Channel>() {
                    Log.e("last friend", it.friendlyName)
                    it!!.messages?.getLastMessages(1, ChatCallbackListener<List<Message>>() {

                        if (it.size > 0)
                            if (it.get(0).hasMedia()) {
                                dataObject.isAttachement = true
                                dataObject.lastMessage = "attachment"
                            } else {
                                dataObject.lastMessage = it.get(0).messageBody
                                dataObject.lastMessageDataAndTime = it.get(0).dateCreated
                    })

                })

            setThreadAdapter(data)
    }
```

I am unable to update two values of the data class, looks like the loop jumping out before getting messages, any help highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A callback is code that is run some time in the future, when the results are received. The loop isn't exiting early, but the callbacks will not be called until after the loop is completed.

Comment: So what ll be work around?

Comment: I don't know enough about what you're doing to say. Your objects will eventually be modified, I'm assuming, but I don't know what API you're working with. You can create a counter that each listener increments, and when it reaches the collection size, you react to the collection now being completely modified. Or you could create a helper that converts the API code into a suspend function and use this in a coroutine. That would result in the cleanest code.

Comment: I am using twilio programmable chat call back to receive last mesaage of each channel

Comment: call             setThreadAdapter(data)
in the ChatCallbackListener

Comment: @Ramesh bro beofre getting called last message listnere loop running outside

Comment: so i am not getting result as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your adapter is getting called before the data retrieved by the callbacks.

there are multiple approached to do that.
But one is below:

fun jhaman() {

```
val data = mutableListOf<Any>()
// to set the adapter with empty message so you can update
setThreadAdapter(data)

val remoteChannelId = 0// todo change this

data.forEachIndexed { index, any ->

channelsObject.getChannel(
            any.remoteChannelId,
            ChatCallbackListener<Channel>() { channel -> 
                Log.e("last friend", any.friendlyName)
                channel.messages?.getLastMessages(1, ChatCallbackListener<List<Message>>() {
                    //update your data what you wana to do in the data object
                    any.apply {
                        // update the data
                    }
                    adapter.updateThreadAdapter(index, any)
                })
            })
}
```

}

// in adapter

```
fun updateThreadAdapter(index: Int, any: Any) {
    list.get(index) = any 
    notifyItemChanged(list)
}
```

Change any to your object.

Disclaimer: I did not run this code because I don't have that chat api in my project. thanks